# R言語 library()での関数の呼び出し時のエラー

Tags: r

```
> library(ggplot2)
 エラー: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
  ファイル 'C:/Users/ytfjv/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rlang/R/rlang.rdb' を開くことができません: No such file or directory
```

上のようなエラーが出ます。
libraryのディレクトリは二つあり、

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/ytfjv/Documents/R/win-library/4.0"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/library"
```

`[1]` に含まれるほとんどの関数を呼び出すことができません。（`[2]` 内の関数は呼び出し可）
どのようにすればよいか、教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

"No such file or directory" = "ファイルやフォルダを開くことが出来ません" というエラーなので、指定したファルダ `C:/Users/ytfjv/Documents/R/win-library/4.0` が存在するかをエクスプローラ等で順に辿って確認してみてください。

Comment: C:/Users/ytfjv/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rlang/R/rlang.rdbは存在しませんでした。また、ggplot2のフォルダは（C:/Users/ytfjv/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ggplot2/R/ggplot2.rdb として）存在しているのですが、なぜか上の存在していないフォルダを開こうとしている状態にあることに今気づきました。